# Unable to access the microphone in chrome, after deployment code to Kubernates environment

Tags: asp.net, .net, google-chrome, azure-aks

We have developed application using the .net 4.5 version and code is deployed to AKS environment.

We added new feature in the app to convert speach to text. Everything works fine locally able to   access the microphone in all browsers.    Post deployment we are able access the microphone in safari and edge browsers. **But in chrome we are unable access the microphone its throws "Domexception Permission Denied error"**.

We use below Javascript code to access the microphone.

> navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
> video: false,
> audio: true
> }).
> then((stream) => {
> console.log('audio start');
> });

[image: [exceptionimage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cu4Dh.png)]

Note that:- The issue happens only after deployment to AKS environment.
if we deploy code on premise server we do not get any issues and able access microphone in all    browsers.

We are looking for the solution at application code and we are not looking for solution which related to browser settings as it would be very difficult to go to each user's browser machine and change the settings.

Any answers or suggestions are highly appreciated.